# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.experimental.numpy'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I ran into an error today that I cannot explain. While trying to implement the tensorflow numpy API, I'm getting the follwing error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XX.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow.experimental.numpy as tnp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.experimental.numpy'
```

I have the latest version of tensorflow and python installed. I've had no issues with importing any other tf packages whatsoever.

Can anybody explain the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Works without any issue with Tensorflow 2.4.1

`import tensorflow.experimental.numpy as tnp`